# "No Matching Function for call" Error

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm working on this project where I have to take input from a file into a vector, then break apart that vector and send elements of it into a class. I'm trying to build a test of the class person but I'm getting this error when I try to do so.

Error:

```
C:\Users\Eric\Dropbox\CSE 2122 - C++\Project Files\Homework09\main.cpp:57: error: no matching function for call to `person::person(int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)'
C:\Users\Eric\Dropbox\CSE 2122 - C++\Project Files\Homework09\main.cpp:9: note: candidates are: person::person(const person&)
C:\Users\Eric\Dropbox\CSE 2122 - C++\Project Files\Homework09\main.cpp:17: note:                 person::person(int, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >)
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

/* Person Class */
class person
{
    public:
        int id;
        vector <float> scores;
        float averageScore;

    /* Person Constructor */
    person(int _id, vector<float> _scores)
    {
    id = _id;
    scores = _scores;

    int total;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < _scores.size(); i++)
    {
        total += _scores[i];
    }

    averageScore = (total / _scores.size());
    }
};

/* Function Prototypes */
string getFileName();
void readFile(string fileName, vector <int> &tempVec);

/* Main */
int main()
{
    vector <int> tempVec;
    vector <int> tempVec2;

    tempVec2.push_back(56);
    tempVec2.push_back(98);
    tempVec2.push_back(78);
    tempVec2.push_back(89);

    int personCount = 0;

    vector <person> personVector;

    string fileName = getFileName();

    readFile(fileName, tempVec);

    personCount = (tempVec.size())/(4);

    person eric = person(110, tempVec2);


}

/* getFileName Function */
string getFileName()
{
    string fileName;
    cout << "Enter the file you wish to read from: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    return fileName;
}

/* readFile Function */
void readFile(string fileName, vector <int> &tempVec)
{
    float x = 0;

    ifstream fin;

    fin.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::in);

    if(!fin.is_open())
    {
        perror(fileName.c_str());
        exit(10);
    }

    while(!fin.fail())
    {
        fin >> x;
        tempVec.push_back(x);
    }

    fin.close();
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `person` constructor takes a `vector` of `float`s, and you are trying to pass `tempVec2` into it, which is a `vector` of `int`s.

Comment: Wow...thanks. I've been staring at that forever, sometimes someone else just needs to take a look to find a stupid mistake.